# Should I flag answers that have been accepted even when they don't answer the question?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I just got a flag declined for flagging [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/270081/ip-conflict-due-to-shared-dsl-connection/270913#270913) as "not an answer". The flagging comment stated "declined - Almost by definition, an accepted answer is an answer. Pointless or bad answer should be downvoted." I was a bit surprised since I made the flag in good faith ([see the September 2011 Newsletter about flagging](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/)). Yeah, I was also a little bit annoyed at losing 10 flag weight, but I'll get over it by the time I post this.

What I really want to know is if the declined flag comment is correct. Should I bypass accepted answers that are clearly comments and not answers? I admit that this is probably a rare situation, but I want to be a better flagger and would like to know what is best practice.

As a more general question, is there a flagging faq that covers all the intricacies of flagging, or at least the best practices? I've been searching for "flag" on meta for days and reading all I can to educate myself. However, I have 18 flags with 3 declined which leaves me with the feeling that I'm missing some fundamental understanding of what's acceptable to flag and what's not. I want to do better than that.

Comment: I will decline a flag, even one made in good faith, if I've noticed a pattern I want to discourage. Generally that one correction is enough to get the flagger nudged in the right direction. These days, any time I click decline I hear about it in meta more often than not, which gives me a chance to clarify why. Mark nailed it.

Answer (score 6):

If it's an accepted answer, there's nothing we can do about it.

In that particular case, a self-accepted answer is 99.999% of the time *always* left alone, because only the op knows what fixed it.

It sucks that they didn't tell us what happened, but that's life.

Although this isn't actually what you asked, I may as well elaborate:

- An accepted answer is almost always left alone
- An answer that is just plain *wrong* (e.g. "Q: What is 1+1? A: 3") should not be flagged, they should be downvoted and a comment explaining why they are wrong. Us mods are real people and we're not experts in all environments so we're not permitted to make judgements on the technical content.
- Feel free to flag things that are really not answers (such as requests for more information, or rants)

Comment: How do you feel about an answer that answers a different question (e.g. "Q: What is 1+1? A: Blue")?

Comment: Wrong answers need downvotes. Answers answering the wrong question need downvotes; they're still an answer, just a wrong one. Incomprehensible [word salad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_salad) can get the ax since they aren't anything.

Comment: @ScottPack - it's very odd that something like that would get the a checkmark, but in any case, it still deserves just a downvote *and a comment* (because usally the answerer is just confused). If it gets three, the poster can get a badge for deleting it themselves!

Comment: When is an answer not an answer? When it makes no attempt to answer the question posed. At that point it's no better than random monkey thrashing.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that if I'd seen that one I also would have flagged it. Learning now that it would have been pointless I've downvoted it instead. Either way, you're correct: That is not an answer. It's not even a reasonable comment.

Don't get too disheartened by the declines. As a general rule they will occur less frequently as your flag weight rises. I've had some for reasons I can't understand but just accept that as part of the deal.

Comment: TBH it just deserves closing as TL and then we can delete it.

Comment: @Iain, you're right. I had only looked at the answer, not the question. Vote cast.